# How to do bifactor ESEM in R?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

Is it possible to do bifactor ESEM in R? Or is it only possible in MPlus?

I want to construct a bifactor ESEM with about 190 items and N=2000, with the WLSMV estimator. I would like to be able to rotate the specific factors and the general factor. I would then prune the low loadings from the specific and general factors so I can test the model as a CFA (this part I know how to do). I would like to be able to specify different numbers of specific factors so I can determine which has the best fit.

I can't seem to find any tutorials online about bifactor ESEM. Only a tutorial on ESEM (but not with bifactor models) in lavaan. https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/efa.html

Has anyone done this before? Does anyone know the packages and the syntax that I could use?

I have tried the lavaan efa function specifying 'bigeomin' rotation. However, this only produces a single level factor model, not a bifactor model, with no loadings onto a general factor in the output.